# Computing $\lim_{(x,y)\to(0,0)}(x^2+1)\cdot\frac{\sin y}{y}$

Tags: limits, multivariable-calculus

Hi I have a limit with two variables in front of me and the book says directly that it is equal with $1$ but for the life of me I dont understand why?? maybe the answer is stupid but I am excausted and I can't see it! Here is the limit:

$$\lim_{(x,y)\to(0,0)}(x^2+1)\cdot\frac{\sin y}{y}$$

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Welcome to math.stackexchange ! It makes the question easier to read if you put the symbols between \$ ... \$ and also prefix math "words" like "lim" and "sin" with a backslash.

Comment: What have you done so far? Do you have any difficulty with the $x$ part?

Comment: If not, you are simply asking how to deal with $\frac{\sin y}{y}$. The snag there is that that limit has been dealt with many times before on this site, so the question is just regarded as a duplicate.

Comment: Nice picture of you two together ;) Anyway, hint: $x^2$ goes to $0$ and $\sin y/y$ to $1$, so...

Comment: But I am afraid I think this should be marked as a duplicate, unless you are worried about how to deal with $\lim_{(x,y)\to(x_0,y_0)}f(x)g(y)$ when you already know $\lim_{x\to x_0}f(x)$ and $\lim_{y\to y_0}g(y)$

Comment: Thanks everyone! I ddnt see your questions at first. sorry. anyway i have gotten my answer. my snag was obviously that the limit of siny/y as y->0 is 1... duh! thanks again and sorry for not answering

Answer (score 2):

Perhaps the easiest way to see this is to keep in mind that 
$$\lim_{z\to z_0} f(z)g(z)=\lim_{z\to z_0} f(z)\lim_{z\to z_0} g(z)$$
when both limits exist on the RHS.

I hope it is clear that
$$\lim_{(x, y)\to (0, 0)}x^2+1=\lim_{x\to 0}x^2+1=1$$
and 
$$\lim_{(x, y)\to (0, 0)}\frac{\sin y}{y}=\lim_{y\to 0}\frac{\sin y}{y}=1.$$

Answer (score 0):

Hint:

$$\frac{\sin y}{y}\underset{y\to0}{\longrightarrow}1$$

And

$$|f(x,y)-1|=\left|(x^2+1)\left(\frac{\sin y}{y}-1+1\right)-1\right|=\left|x^2\left(\frac{\sin y}{y}-1\right)+x^2+\left(\frac{\sin y}{y}-1\right)\right|\leq x^2\left|\frac{\sin y}{y}-1\right|+x^2+\left|\frac{\sin y}{y}-1\right|$$

Comment: Is that really the simplest proof of how to deal with products? Maybe it is?

Comment: @almagest Not the simplest, of course, but if the OP wants a $\varepsilon-\delta$ proof, he may start with this. Anyway, it's not yet clear what he finds unobvious in the question.

Comment: i told you i am excausted! the answer was obviously a DUH! answer!no need for sarcastic comments. thanks anyway...

Comment: @user3670661 I'm not sarcastic. You have not answered any question asked in comments, so I don't even know what you are supposed to know about limits. It's uncomfortable to try to help people who don't seem to want to participate in the elaboration of an answer to their own question.

Comment: I missed the questions sorry... my snag was obviously that the limit of siny/y as y->0 is 1... and i couldnt see how the final solution is 1

Answer (score 0):

This function offers two independent blocks whose limits give values in $\mathbb{R} \setminus \{0\}$ so:
$$
\lim_{(x,y) \to (0,0)}(x^2+1)\cdot\frac{\sin y}{y}=\lim_{x \to 0}(x^2+1)\cdot\lim_{y \to 0}\frac{\sin y}{y} =1 \cdot 1=1
$$